# Attempting to place data from an API onto a modal in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm attempting to put data that I'm getting from an API onto a modal that will appear whenever a button is clicked.

How is this done? I'm able to use the data from the API without the modal, so I know it's not an issue with the syntax of my componentDidMount(). Not sure what the issue is and how it can be resolved.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Nav from './Nav';
import Meal from './Meal';
import meals from './Meals';
import Modal1 from './Modal'


function App() {
  const mealArr = meals.map(item => <Meal food={item.food} picture={item.picture} type={item.id}  />)

  return (
      <div className="content">
        <Nav />
        {mealArr}
        <Modal1 isOpen={false}/>
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import Modal from 'react-modal';

class Modal1 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [],
      isLoaded: false
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        items: json
      })
    })
  }

  render() {

    const allItems = this.state.items;

    let itemArr = allItems.map(item => 
    
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>)

      return (
        <div>
          <Modal>
            {itemArr}
          </Modal>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }

export default Modal1;
```

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Modal1 from 'react-modal';

class Meal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isOpen: false
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.turnOff = this.turnOff.bind(this);
  }
  

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({isOpen: true})
  }

  turnOff() {
    this.setState({isOpen: false})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="meal-container">
        <h2>{this.props.type}</h2>
        <h1>{this.props.food}</h1>
        <img alt="" src={this.props.picture} />
        <p className="steps-button" onClick={this.handleClick}>Steps</p>
        <Modal1 className="modal-1" isOpen={this.state.isOpen}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Meal;
```

Comment: Any reason you're using a function component for `App` and not for the other components? You don't have to but making things consistent makes for a nicer codebase. Also read the documentation for [React portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) as that's a good use-case for modals. [Some more information](https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-react-portals-ab79827732c7).

Comment: what is the problem with the current implementation? are there any errors? I can't understand the issues from the explanation

Comment: @novonimo the text I'm attempting to get from the API is not appearing on the modal. The modal is blank. There's no errors. The items array in state is empty.

Comment: Okay, I've got it. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at `allItems`, it's an empty array before you get the data from the API.

So, for the first render (before component did mount):

```
const allItems = this.state.items  // ----> const allItems = []
```

mapping through an empty array will not produce any error and return another empty array, but when you map through an empty array, don't expect to have any `item` or `item.name`. so the `itemArr` is not as your expectation and cause the issue with rendering it.

to avoid from this issue, check your `allItems` to ensure that the data has arrived.

```
const allItems = this.state.items;
let itemArr = []

if (allItems.length > 0) {
    itemArr = allItems.map(item => (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
}

return (
        <div>
          <Modal>
            {itemArr}
          </Modal>
        </div>
      )
```

Comment: For some reason, the data is still not coming through to this.state.items. Any idea why?

Comment: all the above implementation is in the `render` method, do you sure about it on your implementation? @Andrew